# Smart load switch with inrush control and overvoltage lockout

Tags: power-supply, inrush-current

After I finish making my dc-dc buck-bost converter, voltmeter and ammeter I decided to add a smart load switch to my power supply in order to have the posibility to connect electric motors, bulbs or any element that generete big inrush currents at startup.
Here is my write diagram. I am using the ltc7004 ic (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC7004.pdf) as a load switch.

[image: diagram_image]

I have 2 question regarding to this:

1- How can I control INP pin without using a microcontroller. This pin is CMOS input compatible.

2- This switch will tolerate a short circuit? In the datasheet I not found anything.

Comment: What is "ovlo" in your question title?

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the comment. I recently edit title. Its overvoltage lockout

Comment: OK, thanks. That would be OVLO, not ovlo. Same with your part numbers. Capitals matter!

Comment: How do you want to control the INP or, what is it functionally to do in your circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka I want to control INP pin using CMOS voltages, 0v to turn off output and 5v to turn it on. This pin is "the switch" that's enable or disable output pin. Ideally if its posible I want to use one switch button to enable or disable this pin using the voltages

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing something but, wire your input to a switch that connects to 5 volts and use a pull-down resistor of (say) 10 kohm between INP and 0 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks!. I think this is better and more easy than use a tactile switch that only will complex the circuit. What do you think about my second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This switch has voltage protection features but not current or power protection. Thus "smart" is not an attribute they used for this IC.

It would not be wise to drive a 4A motor with a 40A start surge or locked rotor current unless you add current sensing to control Vinp to create a current limit and hysteretic response like PWM.

The device is not short circuit protected. Although Smart Switches do exist that have this feature. [for example](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps27sa08.pdf) TPS27SA08 36-V, 10-A, Single-Channel Smart High Side Switch

Comment: I will use this ic TPS1HB35 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps1hb35-q1.pdf?ts=1611951589307&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS1HB35-Q1

If I want to use an arduino nano as the microcontroller I understand that ic output pins are used to monitor current and faults. Do I have to use digital outputs of the arduino (0-5v) to control for example EN, LATCH, DIA_EN on the ic pins? Another question, can I protect I/O inputs of the arduino in case of overvoltage using just resistors or I need aditional components like a tvs diode?

Comment: 1) You can 2) if you have excessive crosstalk, try to isolate motor cable and don't share gnd currents